# fig.savfig issue! save file in exact 190 x 190 matplotlib pie chart python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

hello i am facing issue in saving the file in exact width and height
i want to save the file in 190 x 190 but i don't know how to do this
i am currently doing `fig.savfig('image.png',dpi=32)`
when image exports it gives the image of **width=189
height=150**

here is my code

````
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0), inner_radius, color='black', linewidth=3.25, fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

plt.title('Sughosh Work', color='white')
plt.axis('equal')


plt.show()
fig.savefig('chart.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=32, transparent=False)```
````

Comment: You are calling bbox_inches=tight

Comment: so what should i do?
   i want save file to 190 x 190

Comment: Don’t call bbox_inches=tight?

Comment: after that?
 i'll remove it but after that?

Comment: how can i save it in 190x190 with good resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following : [Setting the actual size of figures in matplotlib.pyplot](https://kavigupta.org/2019/05/18/Setting-the-size-of-figures-in-matplotlib/)

You can use the following method to resize your figure :

```
def set_size(fig, size, dpi=100, eps=1e-2, give_up=2, min_size_px=10):
    target_width, target_height = size
    set_width, set_height = target_width, target_height # reasonable starting point
    deltas = [] # how far we have
    while True:
        fig.set_size_inches([set_width, set_height])
        actual_width, actual_height = get_size(fig, dpi=dpi)
        set_width *= target_width / actual_width
        set_height *= target_height / actual_height
        deltas.append(abs(actual_width - target_width) + abs(actual_height - target_height))
        if deltas[-1] < eps:
            return True
        if len(deltas) > give_up and sorted(deltas[-give_up:]) == deltas[-give_up:]:
            return False
        if set_width * dpi < min_size_px or set_height * dpi < min_size_px:
```

You can then call it like that :

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.gca().plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
plt.gca().set_xlabel("x label")
plt.gca().set_ylabel("y label")
set_size(fig, (5, 2.5))
plt.savefig("update-size.png", bbox_inches='tight')
print(imread("update-size.png").shape) # outputs (250, 500, 4)
```

in your case try using `set_size(fig, (1.9, 1.9))` if you want a figure that is 190x190

Comment: I don't see where `get_size` is defined in this answer, but you don't need to jump through these hoops if you don't use `bbox_inches='tight'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *figure* to be exactly 190x190:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.9, 1.9))
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
fig.savefig("MyTinyFigure.png", dpi=100)
print(plt.imread("MyTinyFigure.png").shape) # outputs (190, 190, 4)
```